# How can I store an object by key in a sorted list?

Tags: c#, object, sortedlist

I have two classes.
One class is an object of the type

```cs
public class Taksi
{
    public int num;
    public string brand;
    public string FIO;
    public double mileage;
    // Here i missed get and setters

    public Taksi(int newNum, string newBrand, string newFio, double Mileage)
    {
        this.brand = newBrand;
        this.FIO = newFio;
        this.mileage = Mileage;
        this.num = newNum;
    }
}
```

And the second class stores a sortedList like SortedList <int, object> Park {get; }

```cs
public class sortedList : FileEvent, Gride
{
    SortedList<int, object> Park { get; }

    public sortedList()
    {
        Park = new SortedList<int, object>();
    }
 }
```

in function in class sortedList FileEvent.scanFile (string pathFile)
I fill in the sorted list with the keys and the Taxi object.
in this line Park.Add(Int32.Parse(dataArray[0]), newTaksi);

```cs
void FileEvent.scanFile(string pathFile)
{
    Taksi newTaksi;
    IEnumerable<string> lines = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    try
    {
        lines = File.ReadLines(pathFile);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception when opening file: " + e);
    }

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] dataArray = line.Split('|');
            newTaksi = new Taksi(Int32.Parse(dataArray[0]),
                dataArray[1],
                dataArray[2],
                double.Parse(dataArray[3]));

            Park.Add(Int32.Parse(dataArray[0]), newTaksi);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception when parsing file: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

** How can I get back the taxi object from the sorted list and the data from the object?**

Comment: Do you want to access the object by its `num`? Why do you declare the list as `<int, object>` and not as `<int, Taksi>`?

Comment: Why does it have to be a sorted list? A Dictionary makes more sense for key/value pairs.

Comment: On assignment, I need to use SortedList and get an object from there by number. How can I get an object from this class by number and data from it?

Comment: For example, I would like to iterate over the object forEach, but I cannot do it.

```
 foreach(Taksi s in Park[1234])
            {
                MessageBox.Show(s.FIO.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SortedList<int, Taksi>` instead of `SortedList<int, object>`. If you specify the correct type here, the list knows what type of objects it holds and you can access them as the correct type.

In order to get a taksi by number from the list, you can use the `TryGetValue` method:

```
if(Park.TryGetValue(42, out Taksi myTaksi))
{
    // Number 42 was in the list and you can use it here as myTaksi
}
else
{
    // There is no taxi with number 42 in the list
}
```

If you are certain that a certain number is in the list, you can access it using square brackets:

```
Taksi no42 = Park[42];
```

In order to loop over all objects in the list:

```
foreach(Taksi taksi in Park.Values)
{
    // Do something with taksi
}
```

Or if you want to access the object together with the number it was added under in the list:

```
foreach(var pair in Park)
{
    // pair.Key is the number
    // pair.Value is the Taksi object
}
```